# Plotting filtered rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataset (it is just a sample):

```
Date               Name           Surname             Text
2020/03/20         Joe              Smith          Include details 
2020/03/20       Michael           Jordan        Describe what you've tried
2020/03/21         Bill              Gates          Preserve colouring and details 
2020/03/24         Bill              Gates          Preserve colouring 

...
```

I extracted specific words from text as follows:

```
def extr(txt):
    return(df.loc[df['Text'].str.contains(txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE), 'Name'].tolist())
```

So if I have txt='details' I get the following:

```
extr('details)
```

output

```
['Joe','Bill']
```

After selecting them, I would like to plot Joe and Bill by date, i.e.

```
 2020/03/20         Joe              Smith          Include details 
 2020/03/21         Bill              Gates         Preserve colouring and details
```

I would like to have a scatter plot with on the x-axis the date (sorted of course) and on the y-axis Name.

Since the other 'Bill Gates' does not include details, I am not interested in it.

How can I get this information?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *plot Joe and Bill by date*?

Comment: I would need to plot a scatter plot where on the x-axis I have the date and on the y-axis Name. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the associated dates along with the names, then can do something like this:

```
(df.loc[df['Text'].str.contains('details', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
   .plot.scatter('Date','Name')
)
```

Output:

[image]